# Cut Marks (Interrupted rectangles in the corners)

Tags: print-design, page-layout, print-production

I recently read a post explaining cut marks and their purpose. However, if they're meant as guidelines as to what has to be cut off to create a neat brochure in the right size, why are they still visible on some finished print-outs. I've seen multiple text packets where these corners are there (in the text packets during exams etc.) - so I'm wondering why they're still visible despite only being guidelines.

I'm a beginner at this, so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question w/ an obvious answer :)

Comment: Because its designer did not pay attention, most likely.

Comment: It is possible to have a document with intentionally visible cut marks. I have used cut marks to see if the user printed the document with fit to view as opposed to original size. This way i know whether or not the image is to scale or not. You'd be surprised to know that 50% of students would get marked down because they couldn't uncheck the fit to page option as per instructions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cut marks are there to be used by professional printers using professional machines. Basicly, you need to know what they are and how they work, to be able to use the cut marks as per their actual purpose.

From the designer's side, many times you will send a PDF in both versions, with AND without cut marks, to be used for different purposes. However, this does not always happen, and documents just circulate 'as they are'.

Then, if 'normal' people (as in, people not working in a print shop) get a PDF saved with cut marks, it is very likely that:

1. they will use an office/home type printer, which just fits the entire artwork, including cut marks, into a predefined paper size (A4, US Letter). The cut marks become just part of the artwork with a normal office/home printer.
2. they will not even know — or have in interest in — removing cut marks from pages.

Comment: Those pesky 'normals' have a lot to answer for.

Answer (score 0):

Lucian answer is 100% right but there is also another explaantion.
Because they should be there.
I think bottom othe carton of milk is the best, exaggerated, evidence. If a box is mutliple colors, youwill see a lot of color marks, registration, maybe even some fan with multitude of strokes width. They are all there to check, at any given time that the printing machine is doing ok. Each print is a test print that can be checked and, without stoping printing process, adjustments can be made.

Cut marks can be used with same/similar way. You just use the same 25% of everything registration color for crops marks and use those as, well, registration marks. Or you print a helluva lot of CMY "templates" and then just overprint with black on different machine in different time.

On exams they are thre because it don't make sense to pay for cutting them out. It takes time and money and tests are used once. I've seen such test that CMY were printed in advance and then few variations of K plates were printed onto them. To lower the risk of anyone having time of reading the question cutting was not needed but marks were used as registration marks.